# Exclude subsite urls while using sw precache in angular5

Tags: angular, angular5, service-worker, sw-precache

Can I exclude some urls while using sw precache for generating service worker.Below is my swprecache.config.json

```
module.exports = {
navigateFallback: '/index.html',
stripPrefix: 'dist',
root: 'dist/',
staticFileGlobs: [
  'dist/index.html',
  'dist/**.js',
  'dist/**.css',
  'dist/**.ico',
  'dist/assets/images/**.jpg',
  'dist/assets/images/**.png',
  'dist/assets/images/**.gif',
  'dist/assets/js/**/**.js',
  'dist/assets/js/**.js',
  'dist/assets/css/**.css',
  'dist/assets/fonts/**.{js,html,css,png,jpg,gif,svg,eot,ttf,woff,ico}',
  'dist/**.{js,html,css,png,jpg,gif,svg,eot,ttf,woff,ico}',
   '!dist/Subscription/**.{js,html,css,png,jpg,gif,svg,eot,ttf,woff,ico}'
],

runtimeCaching: [{
  urlPattern: /^https:\/\/netdna\.bootstrapcdn\.com\//,
  handler: 'networkFirst'
}]
```

};

I tried to use not operator like '!dist/Subscription/**.{js,html,css,png,jpg,gif,svg,eot,ttf,woff,ico}'.But its not working.So that I am getting cannot match any route error while navigating to subsite.After clearing browser data only, I can navigate to subsite. Can anyone pls help me to fix it,pls find my error [image]

Thanks

Comment: Ok, but now it looks like you have a angular routing problem instead of a sw-precache problem. What routes do you have defined?

Comment: if routing problem means.It should not navigate to subsite for the first time also right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after generating serviceworker,I checked whether the request contains "Subscription" in fetch event like below which is working fine

```
 self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
if (event.request.method === 'GET') {
// Should we call event.respondWith() inside this fetch event handler?
// This needs to be determined synchronously, which will give other fetch
// handlers a chance to handle the request if need be.
var shouldRespond;
if (event.request.url.match('^.*(\/Subscription\/).*$')) {
    return false;
}
  // OR

if (event.request.url.indexOf('/Subscription/') !== -1) {
    return false;
}

 .............}})
```

Its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
staticFileGlobs: [
  'dist/index.html',
  'dist/*.{js,css,ico}',
  'dist/!(Subscription)/**/*.{js,html,css,png,jpg,gif,svg,eot,ttf,woff,ico}'
]
```

found here: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-precache/issues/97

Comment: Thanks,this is also not working kindly find my error screenshot after using this